# c# does 1.09:00:00 timespan mean 9am tomorrow?

Tags: c#, datetime, timer, timespan

I have a routine which is suppose to run at 9am everyday....

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
   log.Info("Info - Service Start");
   string timeToRunStr = "09:00";
   var timeStrArray = timeToRunStr.Split(';');
   foreach (var strTime in timeStrArray)
   {
        timeToRun.Add(TimeSpan.Parse(strTime));
   }
    ResetTimer();
}

void ResetTimer()
{
   log.Info("Info - Reset Timer");
   try
   {
       TimeSpan currentTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
       TimeSpan nextRunTime = timeToRun[0];
       foreach (TimeSpan runTime in timeToRun)
       {
           if (currentTime < runTime)
           {
               nextRunTime = runTime;
               // log.Info("Info - in loop");
               _timer = new Timer((nextRunTime - currentTime).TotalSeconds * 1000);
               break;
           }
           else {
             TimeSpan test = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 16, 51, 0).AddDays(1).Subtract(DateTime.Now);
             nextRunTime = test;
              _timer = new Timer((nextRunTime).TotalSeconds * 1000);
            }
        }               
        log.Info("Info - Timer : " + (nextRunTime - currentTime).TotalSeconds * 1000);
        log.Info("Info - nextRuntime : " + nextRunTime);
        log.Info("Info - currentTime : " + currentTime);
        _timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
        _timer.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Error("This is my timer error - ", ex);
    }
}
```

it runs at 9am then next run time it says 1.09:00:00 does this mean 9am tomorrow?

Comment: What is your `Culture` ?

Comment: What does _"it says 1.09:00:00"_ mean? And why don't you simply inspect the properties of your `TimeSpan` object *before* you attempt to "reverse-engineer" the `.ToString()` (my guess) formatting?

Comment: In this instance, the format is dd.hh:mm:ss (days, hours, minutes, seconds) - but the string will be variable depending on the size of your timespan, your culture, and whether the end of time has been reached or not. It doesn't mean nine am tomorrow without any context.

Comment: No, it means a timespan of 33 hours (1 day + 9 hours). How a date/time is calculated from that depends on how you use it.

Comment: This doesn't do much: 'string timeToRunStr = "09:00"; var timeStrArray = timeToRunStr.Split(';');'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [MSDN Documentation:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx)

> A TimeSpan value can be represented as [-]d.hh:mm:ss.ff, where the
>   optional minus sign indicates a negative time interval, the d
>   component is days, hh is hours as measured on a 24-hour clock, mm is
>   minutes, ss is seconds, and ff is fractions of a second. That is, a
>   time interval consists of a positive or negative number of days
>   without a time of day, or a number of days with a time of day, or only
>   a time of day.

In your instance, the TimeSpan is 1 day, 9 hours, 0 minutes and 0 seconds.

In answer to your actual question:

> it runs at 9am then next run time it says 1.09:00:00 does this mean
>   9am tomorrow?

It depends - if you add the timespan to your current time (i.e. when your current batch finishes) it will give you a time of around 6pm the follwing day. You'd need to take DateTime.Now.Date (midnight of the given date) and add the timespan to that to get 9AM the next day.

However, there are plenty of [scheduling](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) [components](http://code.google.com/p/ncron/) out there that you might find easier to use (or at least read the code for) - depending on your requirements for accuracy and recovery.

In your original method, you might find it easier to simply:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
   log.Info("Info - Service Start");
   DateTime startTime = DateTime.Date.AddHours(9); //9AM Today
   timeToRun.Add(startTime); 
   CreateTimer();
}

void CreateTimer()
{
   log.Info("Info - Reset Timer");
   try
   {
      if(_timer == null){
         _timer = new Timer(3600 * 1000); //once an hour
         _timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
         _timer.Start();
      }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Error("This is my timer error - ", ex);
    }
}
```

Then, in your timer_elapsed event, you just do the following (excuse the event signature, it's from memory):

```
void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
   if(DateTime.Now > timeToRun[0])
   {
      //Code to run the job
      //Then we reset the timer - can do this here or at the end of the job code
      timeToRun[0] = DateTime.Date.AddDays(1).AddHours(9); //9AM tomorrow.
    }

 }
```

Your reset timer is too complex - you don't need all that code. You just create a timer, have it check every hour, and, if the time is now greater than the job run time, run the job, and move the next run time to be 9AM tomorrow. That's all you need to do for a simple timer like this.

Issues with this approach include the fact that it's not granular; the job might not kick off at **exactly** 9AM, so if that's important, it's probably better to investigate one of the linked scheduling libraries I mentioned.

Comment: hmm ok so in my way what do i have to change to make it run at 9am everyday please

Comment: @Beginner Updated my answer with additional example.

Answer (score 7):

1.09:00:00 means a time span of 1 day and 9 hours